# How was it possible to make existing Java classes subclasses of AnyRef in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, bytecode

Scala inheritance hierarchy diagram:

[image]

The above diagram from the book *Scala for the Impatient* shows that all the Java classes are subclasses of the `AnyRef` class.

> Figure 8–1 shows the inheritance hierarchy of Scala classes. The classes that correspond to the primitive types in Java, as well as the type `Unit`, extend `AnyVal`. All other classes are subclasses of the `AnyRef` class, which is a synonym for the `Object` class from the Java or .NET virtual machine.
>   Both `AnyVal` and `AnyRef` extend the `Any` class, the root of the hierarchy.

How was that achieved without changing the Java classes? Is it something that is taken care of at the bytecode level?

Comment: It's just a trick of the Scala compiler.

Comment: It's a rule enforced by the compiler but it doesn't impact the bytecode. You can find the "implementation" of `AnyRef` here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library-aux/scala/AnyRef.scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm by no way a Scala expert, but have 20 years of Java experience, including JVM.

My interpretation is that the sentence

> All other classes are subclasses of **the AnyRef class, which is a
>   synonym for the Object class from the Java** or .NET virtual machine.

*(emphasis mine)* explains it perfectly.

To the JVM, there's no `AnyRef` class. The text calls `AnyRef` a synonym, and the JVM doesn't have such a concept. So, probably the Scala compiler replaces occurrences of `AnyRef` with `java.lang.Object`. And of course, all Java classes are subclasses of `java.lang.Object`, which just got a new name in the Scala compiler, thus making them all inherit from `AnyRef` (a.k.a. `Object`)

I bet you won't find an `AnyRef.class` entry in any Scala runtime JAR library, meaning that to the JVM, a class like `AnyRef` doesn't exist.

Comment: +1, Although this just moves the question to "How then, is `java.lang.Object` / `System.Object` aka `scala.AnyRef` a subclass of `scala.Any`"?

Comment: @JörgWMittag in a Scala context, can Java source code check e.g. `"ABC" instanceof scala.Any` and get a `true` result? I'd be very surprised if this were possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is something that often confuses beginners. There was a [very similar question on Software Engineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/369631/1352) recently. The simple answer is: MAGIC!

Yes, really.

The Scala compiler doesn't have to abide by the rules of the Scala language. In some sense, it *is* the rules of the Scala language! It has to implement and enforce them, but it doesn't have to follow them. And it most certainly doesn't have to follow the rules of the Java language.

So, the way it does it, is really simple: whenever some Scala program does something that depends on `java.lang.String` behaving as if it was a subclass of `scala.AnyRef`, it generates code that behaves as if `java.lang.String` were a subclass of `scala.AnyRef`.

That's it.

You could also ask how Scala makes Java primitives objects that are instances of classes which are subclasses of `scala.AnyVal`. Or, you could ask how you, the programmer, can see the private implementations of two classes when you open the sourcecode of the two files in two editor windows, even though the language says that you can't see private implementations from the outside.

The reason is always the same: because you are sitting *outside* of the language, the language rules don't apply to you.

From the other direction, people often ask why they can subclass `sealed` classes from Java or call methods declared as `private[this]`. The reason is again the same: because the Java compiler doesn't have to play by Scala's rules. It doesn't even *know* about Scala's rules.